# BLE multiple devices GATT callback

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working with the BLE and Android and I managed to connect multiple devices to an Android device. I am trying to send some data from those multiple devices at same time. However I am failing to do so. Since the data I am sending is a few KB I am sending a lot of notifications from each device. Something like 100 from each device with a few milliseconds in between each message.
When I just have 1 device everything is fine. When I have multiple devices, the first device is ok but the rest are dropping data.

Is what I am trying impossible to achieve. Do I need to handle them one by one in order? If I fire too much consecutive messages I block the next operation until the one before finished?

Or am I handling the callback wrong maybe? I saw some solution using queues but I think again the queue can handle only certain amount of messages so I will end up with same issue?

Comment: Android, as GATT client, never drops incoming notifications as far as I know. Check the sending side that your flow control is correct so you don't accidentally drop data before it's even sent over the air. You can use air sniffer or extract Android's hci log ("snoop log") to see if I'm correct.

Comment: I think you are right. What is actually happening is that the sending side fills up the que waiting for ack from Android. So, basically the Android is not sending ack fast enough, it is processing all the notification it receives but just not fast enough since it receives a lot. For example when I use only 1 device it is 100/100, when I have 5 it is 70/100 for one and rest are then like 30/100.